# Connection Error SMTP python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I've been using python for a bit now and have been using the email function without any errors in the past but on the latest program I have made I've been getting this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "daemon.py", line 62, in <module>
    scraper.run()
    File "c:\cfsresd\scraper.py", line 48, in run
    self.scrape()
    File "c:\cfsresd\scraper.py", line 44, in scrape
    handler(msg)
    File "daemon.py", line 57, in handler
    server.ehlo()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 385, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 318, in putcmd
    self.send(str) 
    File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 310, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
    smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I used the same email code for all my projects but this is first time is done it. I've tried adding the connect() but that made no difference. Below is email section of my script

```
msg = MIMEText ('%s - %s' % (msg.text, msg.channel))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    msg['Subject'] = "msg.channel"
    msg['From'] = ('removed')
    msg['To'] = ('removed')
    server.login('user','password')
    server.sendmail(msg.get('From'),msg["To"],msg.as_string())
    server.close()
    server.ehlo()
    server.quit()
    print 'sent'
```

cheers for any help

shaggy

Comment: Is your connection failing?  Is this the same connection string you typically use? I think `smtplib.SMTP` takes host and port as different arguments, though perhaps it also handles it as you specify it there

Comment: email still get sent but then error come up and script stops

Comment: here is one i made that works via my github [link](https://github.com/Shaggs/SMTP-for-py/blob/master/SMTP-for-py.py)

Comment: Yup, that makes me think my answer is probably right, that code in your link doesn't have the extra `close()` and `ehlo()` calls

Comment: tried with close () and ehlo() no change

Comment: You could try the default of `yagmail` package (see answer below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

all sorted took a few idea and tried the code below

```
msg = MIMEText ('%s - %s' % (msg.text, msg.channel))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
server.starttls()
server.login('user','pass')
msg['Subject'] = "msg.channel"
msg['From'] = ('from')
msg['To'] = ('to')
server.sendmail(msg.get('From'),msg["To"],msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

So i removed ehlo(), close() and port number. now i have to workout how to change the subject to msg.channel so it changes each time.

thanks all

Comment: I removed ehlo(), close() and the port number like you did, but I still have this problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using SMTP's empty constructor, then call `connect(host, port)`:

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.connect('smtp.gmail.com', '587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
```

Comment: re-read post and tried forgot () in topline but sill same error disregard old comments sorry

Comment: Call connect('smtp.google.com', '587'), not connect('smtp.google.com:587')

Comment: i have all ways called smtp.gmail.com but tried with smtp.google.com and get error 11004 get addrinfo fail

Answer (score 2):

You can still have an encrypted connection with the smtp server by using the SMTP_SSL class without needing the starttls call (shorter). You don't need to be calling the ehlo every time, that's done automatically when needed, and when connecting to the default port, don't have to supply one when creating instances SMTP* classes.

```
msg = MIMEText ('%s - %s' % (msg.text, msg.channel))
msg['To'] = ','.join(receivers)
msg['Subject'] = 'msg.channel'
msg['From'] = 'someone@somedomain.com'
```

Using SMTP with the starttls:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
server.starttls()
server.login('user', 'password')
server.sendmail(msg['From'], receivers, msg.as_string())
```

and now with the SMTP_SSL class

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
server.login('user', 'password')
server.sendmail(msg['From'], receivers, msg.as_string())
```

and finally

```
server.quit()
```

Comment: says incorrect protocol i like the server.startttls () personally

Comment: So what's this `msg` object in the MIMEText constructor? And what's `channel`?

Comment: Does `sendmail()` really require the headers to be populated in `msg` as well as specified in its params?

Comment: Oh. `msg.channel` is just a string. It's the subject header. The `MIMEText` constructor takes a single arg: the body of the message. The SSL version is the first of the many solutions I've run across that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ehlo` after `close`.  That seems unlikely to ever succeed.  Also, `quit` does `close` so you can probably just get rid of the `ehlo` and `close` calls near the end

Answer (score 1):

For Pyhton 3.6.*
 Note : In gmail it will work only if 2-Step verification is turned off.
 Allow gmail to open via low secured app.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_addr = 'sender-email-id'
to_addr = 'receiver-email-id'
text = 'Hi Friend!!!'

username = 'sender-username'
password = 'password'

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = to_addr
msg['Subject'] = 'Test Mail'
msg.attach(MIMEText(text))


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(from_addr,to_addr,msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of `yagmail`, a package that should make it really easy to send an email.

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('user','password')
yag.send(to = 'to@gmail.com', subject = 'msg.channel')
```

when `yag` leaves scope, it will auto-close.

I would also advise you to register in keyring once, so you'll never have to write the password in a script. Just run once:

```
yagmail.register('user', 'password')
```

You can then shorten it to this:

```
SMTP().send('to@gmail.com', 'msg.channel')
```

You can install it with pip or pip3 (for Python 3). You can also [read more about it](https://www.github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), with functionality as easily adding attachments, inline images/html, aliases etc.

Comment: `yagmail.Connect(...): AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Connect'` Importing yagmail from yagmail - same thing.

Comment: @TomRussell Has since been updated to SMTP. I updated the answer, thanks for taking the time to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried to send an e-mail from Celery (as a Docker container). I added env_file to the worker and beat containers in a docker compose file.

```
env_file: ./env/dev/.env
```

In that file I have an e-mail configuration.

```
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER=your_mail
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=your_password
EMAIL_PORT=587
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error just by removing this line:

```
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

> raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')

if you had this error you my be  want install this :

```
pip install django-smtp-ssl
```

this one to install smtp library and ssl protocol

its work perfecly for me

Answer (score 0):

Believe me or not solution is very simple....

Simply just don't close the connection our in other words don't quit the server.

remove `"server.quit()"`.

now you'll be able to send as many mails you need to.